# How to write on the android status bar

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I'm trying to do something like this in my `onCreate()` method.

[image]

```
@TargetApi(21)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#444444"));
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#565656"));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#4d4d4d")));
    writeOnStatusBar("Hello world");
}
```

Comment: Create a custom `Toolbar`. You can find several tutorials on how to do that is you search.

Comment: I do not think Android allows you to do that. However, you can hide the bar and add custom `TextView`. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status)

Comment: I just found xml ways, is there a way by the code to do that? @SusmitAgrawal

Comment: not sure if it's possible to write on status bar. I looked over the Android docs but could not find a single res available. I tried a hack of setting a negative marginTop to be able to reverse a textview, but once it gets to the status bar, the textview hides automatically behind and is not on top of it anymore.